# Entity-Framework Join Explanation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, join

I have the following entities

```
//Active Auction Entity
public class ActiveAuction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int? FirstAuctionId { get; set; }

    public int? SecondAuctionId { get; set; }

    public int? ThirdAuctionId { get; set; }

    public virtual Auction FirstAuction { get; set; }

    public virtual Auction SecondAuction { get; set; }

    public virtual Auction ThirdAuction { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
// Auction Entity
public class Auction
{
    public int AuctionId { get; set; }

    public AuctionStatus AuctionStatus { get; set; }

    public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

}
```

---

```
// Department Entity
public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    public int? AdminId { get; set; }

    public virtual Admin Admin { get; set; }
}
```

---

What I'm trying to do is to get `Active Auctions` with `Auctions` loaded and `Auction` also have `Departments` loaded
I know that I should write `Include` for every object to be loaded so the generated SQL by EF will have join statement to select there object for me

but this is the existing code

```
 using (var dc = DataContext())
    {
        await dc.Auction
           .Include("Department.Admin")
           .Where(i => i.Id == id && i.AuctionStatus == AuctionStatus.Accepted).ToListAsync();

        return await dc.ActiveAuction.
           SingleOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);
    }
```

I don't know How but this code works and the returned `ActiveAuctions` include all desired objects

I checked for SQL executed against the database and as expected it generate to separate queries.

I want an explanation to understand how the returned `ActiveAcutions` loaded with the other mentioned entities!!?

Comment: Is `Categories.Admin` a typo for `Department.Admin`? or did you remove `Categories` from the `Auction` object to shorten code?

Comment: it should be Department.Admin I fixed that, Admin is another existing entity also

Comment: Great, consider using strongly typed inclusions (ie. `.Include(a => a.Department.Admin)`.  It will avoid misspelling/including objects that don't exist.

Comment: and to answer you question, I **believe** it's because you did the two queries in the same context.  EF then realizes that the primary keys match and then links up your data.

Comment: I thought about some kind of merging happened in memory,but I can't find any article talk about this

Comment: Another option would be to investigate the source code: EF6--> https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

Comment: Actually, try disabling tracking in the first line within your `using` and see if you get the same result?

Comment: with this first line within `using` block commented the all the entities are `null` if this what you mean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89715/discussion-between-mohamed-badr-and-johan).

Comment: Are you **positive** you have disabled lazy loading? If you haven't, then it's probably just loading them when you access them for reading

Comment: @Jcl Yes, I'm 100% positive lazy loading is disabled , to be sure I commenting the first line within `using` block will make all objects withinn `ActiveAuction` equals null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is simple. As you most likely know, Entity Framework tracks entities you fetched from database, mostly to detect changes to them and apply those changes to database when you call `SaveChanges`. However, that means EF context has kind of cache of entities fetched from database so far.

**EDIT**: As correctly pointed in comments by @GertArnold - my explanation with dynamic proxies was completely wrong - it works this way even if `ProxyCreationEnabled` is `false`. The real reason is relationship fix up which is performed by entity framework when `DetectChanges` is called (it is called implicitly on various events, like attaching entity to context, or executing query over `DbSet`). During that relationship fix up, EF synchronizes navigation properties and foreign keys which in your case causes behavior you observe. More about relationship fix up [in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx)

To verify this you may use this simple code:

```
using (var ctx = new TestEntities()) {
     ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;                
     ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;                
     var code = ctx.Codes.First();                
     var error = ctx.Errors.First();
     Debug.Assert(Object.ReferenceEquals(error.Code, code));                                
}
```

Here I first fetch some entity (Code), then I fetch another entity (Error) which has navigation property Code. You see that *lazy loading is disabled*. The following assert will pass, because error.Code and code is the same .NET object, which confirms it was fetched from context cache.

Comment: Despite the broad explanation you don't really get to the real reason: relationship fixup. Proxy creation is not required for that to happen, so imho mentioning that only adds noise.

Comment: @GertArnold if I understand correctly, first loaded Auction and department, second loaded ActiveAuction, isn't it supposed to work that way?

Comment: @GertArnold thanks for pointing that out - indeed I was completely wrong with my explanation about dynamic proxies.

Comment: So the real reason is that the result of the first query (`dc.Auction...`) happens to include the three `Auction`s the `ActiveAuction` of the second query refers to.

Comment: Yeah but this I think I pointed out even in original answer with dynamic proxies.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you are seeing is because EF internally maintains object cache per each DB context instance. Every time when query is executed, EF first checks internal cache to see if it contains neccessary entity. If entity is found, then it is returned from cache without even querying database.

In your sample here it what happens:

- First query gets some `Auction` entities and add them to cache;
- Second query gets filtered `ActiveAuction` entities and add them to cache;
- When you inspect results of second query you see that properties are already filled because they were found in cache by key;

You can change this behavior by changing `MergeOption` setting on database context instance. This setting changes how EF merges results from database to cache.

Possible values are as follows:

> *AppendOnly (default value)*
>
> Objects that do not exist in the object context are attached to the context. If an object is already in the
>   context, the current and original values of object's properties in the
>   entry are not overwritten with data source values. The state of the
>   object's entry and state of properties of the object in the entry do
>   not change. AppendOnly is the default merge option.
>
> *NoTracking*
>
> Objects are maintained in a Detached state and are not tracked in the
>   ObjectStateManager. However, Entity Framework-generated entities and
>   POCO entities with proxies maintain a reference to the object context
>   to facilitate loading of related objects.
>
> *OverwriteChanges*
>
> Objects that do not exist in the object context are attached to the
>   context. If an object is already in the context, the current and
>   original values of object's properties in the entry are overwritten
>   with data source values. The state of the object's entry is set to
>   Unchanged, no properties are marked as modified.
>
> *PreserveChanges*
>
> Objects that do not exist in the object context are attached to the
>   context.

(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.mergeoption(v=vs.110).aspx)

And here is a good article that describes all the options in more details and contains some code samples as well.

http://www.develop1.net/public/post/Do-you-understand-MergeOptions.aspx

EDIT: Just wanted to add that default behavior can lead to strange results if the first query does projection of entity (for example, selects only some columns). In this case entity will still be added to the cache even if it is only half loaded. This means that second query will return half loaded entity as well.

Comment: The ObjectContext API is pretty much deprecated.

Comment: @GertArnold. It does not matter as `DBContext` is just a wrapper around `ObjectContext`, so principles stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `.Include("Department.Admin")` since EF don't load inner inclusions like yours, say, `Admin`.

**Note that**, when you work with EF code first, It's better to determine the real relationships among tables, whether in classes or using fluent API, to meet a good design without anomaly. So, using three `Auction`s in `ActiveAuction` without any clarification may disturb you.

**Another thing** is that, It seems you're using `ActiveAuction` as foreign key in each `Auction` without any declaration! So change your `Auction` class to this:

```
public class Auction
{
    [ForeignKey("ActiveOne")]
    public int AuctionId { get; set; }

    public AuctionStatus AuctionStatus { get; set; }

    public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual ActiveAuction ActiveOne { get; set; } //match this name

}
```

With this in mind, I believe that there are some ambiguities in your models. Let's speak about the query. As you said :

> What I'm trying to do is to get `ActiveAuctions` with `Auctions` loaded
>   and `Auction` also have `Departments` loaded

So you can use something like this query:

```
await context.Auctions.Include("Department").Include("ActiveOne")
.Where(i => i.id == id && i.AuctionStatus == AuctionStatus.Accepted)
.Select(i => i.ActiveOne).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: "You can't use .Include("Department.Admin") since EF don't load inner inclusions like yours" what do you mean !? please explain this.

Comment: You can't use nested members inside `Include`, or at least it wont work properly, I've experienced in working with EF specially Code first about 4 years.

Answer (score 0):

When EF loads any entities it hooks them up with existing entities in its cache so that the model is complete with all the references pointing to any loaded objects.

Answer (score -2):

"Lazy loading is the process whereby an entity or collection of entities is automatically loaded from the database the first time that a property referring to the entity/entities is accessed."
See this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: While the OP's problem may relate to lazy loading but how actually it works in this specific case should be explained more. As you see there is no *clear relationship between Auction and ActiveAuction* here. The first query seems to just load everything related to Auction but then the ActiveAuction (used in the second query) seems to be filled with loaded data *automatically*?

Comment: @Hopeless if lazy loading is enabled, the OP might be lazy loading them (without him noticing)... it was my very first thought about the question, actually.

Comment: @Jcl as I understand lazy loading will load *related objects* accessed via navigation properties. But in this case could you point out what are the related objects of what objects? The loaded objects here are `ActiveAuction` but are that ***clearly*** related to `Auction`? I don't see any relationship or some kind of navigation property access here. That's what confusing about the OP's question. Also I'm not very sure if   lazy loading is related here, so I was just asking against this answer for more explanation.

Comment: @Hopeless maybe I understood the question wrong, but I think the OP's question is something like: "why are `FirstAuction`, `SecondAuction` and `ThirdAuction` [and its related `Department` and `Admin` properties] already loaded when I have loaded those entities *in a different query* in the context"... if that's right, then lazy loading could be indeed related (it seems its not, based on the comments, but I understand how it *could* be related)